# shortcut for konsole

Tags: shortcuts, keys, konsole

I am running Kubuntu 14.04 and cannot get Konsole to open with the usual shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and have looked on various forums and configured "shortcuts and gestures" to add another entry to open Konsole but when I fill in the various options including the command/url option and include the Konsole app in the "home" directory, when I try the key combination I get Kate opening instead!  Any ideas on how to fix this issue?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is as follows:

1. Right click on the 'K-Menu' icon and select 'Edit Applications'
2. Navigate to System --> Konsole
3. Select the 'Advanced' Tab
4. Click on the long tab next to 'Current shortcut key' and type in your required key combination

That is all that is required, I attach a screenshot showing the menu on my own system:

[image]

KDE will warn you of any keyboard shortcuts clashes and give you the option of reassigning a currently used key combination to Konsole if required...